# Result List<AggregateResult> to Integer

Tags: apex

I have problem.

I need to assign a query result to Integer.
I miss something.

```
List<AggregateResult> result = [SELECT COUNT_DISTINCT(LoginHistory.UserId) total FROM AuthSession WHERE UserType = 'Customer Portal User'];
Integer x = result[0].get( 'total' );
```

And this is illegal assigement object to integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to typecast Object to Integer.

```
Integer x = (Integer) result[0].get('total');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this like below. This also works fine.

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(result[0].get('total'));
```

**Reference Url:**

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_integer.htm
- [SObject Numeric field - Integer.valueOf() vs casting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149379/sobject-numeric-field-integer-valueof-vs-casting)